# Using an encrypted partition as a file, for backup purposes

Tags: backup, partition-copy

I use OneDrive for backup. Normally, I just drag-and-drop my files there using the browser interface. This is mostly not too private information, just some work stuff still in development.

I also have a LUKS partition. How can I backup it in OneDrive treating it as a file (everything is a file in, isn't it?)?

I already verified that a file in the same size 3.5GB can be stored there. I just need a way to copy the partition there.

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: @Keltari: Ubuntu

Comment: So what options you have entirely depend on the size of the partition.  However, your biggest hurtle, is that OneDrive does not typically synchronize the file extensions that normally would be associated with something like this

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this, but it requires a lot of steps and possibly additional software.  First, you would need to take an image of the partition.  There are *many* ways to accomplish this.  Check this [article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19901/how-to-make-a-disk-image-and-restore-from-it-later) out from AskUbuntu, as it lists several good methods of creating an image.  The seconds part is uploading that image to OneDrive.  There is no OneDrive client for Linux, so you would have to use a 3rd party tool.  Here is a [list](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/best-unofficial-microsoft-onedrive-apps-for-linux/) of a few apps that can connect to OneDrive from Linux.  I know there are more, you can google for them.

The above would work, but using an image of a partition is limiting, as it would require you to restore the partition to access the data.  It would be easier to just create an encrypted Zip, 7z, etc archive of the data and copy that to OneDrive.  This will allow you to easily restore the file just about anywhere, while still having security.